# CSS Table cells width not consistent but I need first column to be larger

Tags: html, css

Right here is my [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ju43rpgs/). Now what I am trying to do is build a planner, but i'm only in the html and css stages at the moment.

If you look at the table part where I have the **Name** table header and then all of the days monday through friday, I would like to make it so that the Monday-Friday fields are the same width but the name field is larger.

I need to avoid using fixed widths aka setting `33%` to each `<td/>` as the way the planner will respond is quite specific.

Can I do this without setting a fixed width?

Cheers

**EDIT:**
I've come up with a way, using nested tables and the min-width idea from @Antony SUTHAKAR J which puts all the columns at the correct width, but now I can't get the colours to work within the nested table. I can see it's because I cant get the nested table to adopt the height of the parent `<td/>`. Now i've set the parent `<td/>` to have a height of 100% etc as you can see in the code.

Is there something I can do here now? Without setting a manual height.

**[New Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ju43rpgs/2/)**

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "colours to work within the nested table". I'm reading this [New Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ju43rpgs/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `min-width` property [Ex. `min-width: 150px;`] to the first column in the table.
Try this I hope it works.

This will be the minimum width and not the fixed width. So if the column has more text it will stretch itself to fit the content as well.

Cool!

Answer (score 0):

Add **day** class on each weekday column.

```
.day {
  width: 40px;
}
```

Working Example (JS Fiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/ju43rpgs/1/

Comment: The OP specifically asks "Can I do this without setting a fixed width?"